# How would I transfer data from a Node.JS web app to a JavaScript client on another website/server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a Node.JS backend running on Heroku which pulls data from a Google sheet. This app will run once a day to pull updated data from the Google Sheet.

I also have a client written in HTML, CSS & JS which will need to draw that data from the backend.

The problem is, the client **runs on a different server** than than the Node.JS backend. This means I have to have the Node.JS backend update some form of database, then have the client download that data.

Some important information:

- I don't have access to the client server, but of course I can access the backend.
- I only need to transfer a very small amount of data (only 4 pieces of data).
- I am doing this as a volunteer project, and therefore anything suggested needs to be **free**.

These are the options I have considered:

## Option 1: Use Heroku Postgres

This is the option I initially wanted to use. However, I learnt that the credentials to access the database change every so often, so that means the final product may not be completely hands-free.

## Option 2: Find an external SQL database host

This is the more likely option of the two. However, I've found that many free database host are insecure and difficult to use. I had a look at **000webhost**, but I quickly learnt the database was hosted on `localhost` - this meant it couldn't be accessed by my client.

Which of these options, if any, are the best? What other methods can I use to accomplish this? Could someone please give me some recommendations on services which I could use?

Comment: How about exposing an API in your backend which would accept connections from the client? Your client application could just issue a GET request to the backend server through AJAX and get the data. To secure it, you could introduce a simple JWT authentication for the backend API. Of course, in order to do this, the backend application would have to be up all the time, not just when it pulls the google sheet.

Comment: Due to the nature of the service I am using, I can't have the application constantly running since that would use up all of my allowed uptime. I need some way to store the information on a server that is up most of the time.